# Add new pages on PDF and write the same marksheet content on next pages (FPDF python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pdf, fpdf

I am making a **Mark sheet** software that takes input of marks and add student data on the pdf doc. page. But every time I call the function it writes content only at the documents first and others are blank.

from fpdf import FPDF
file1= FPDF()

```
def write_pdf(roll):
    file1.add_page()
    file1.set_font('Arial', '', 17)
    file1.set_left_margin(45)
    file1.ln(10)
    file1.write(5, roll)
    file1.output('fir_sem.pdf','f')

def onClick():
    rno='1400654070012'
    write_pdf(rno)
```

I want that every time I click on the button. New page add on document and the roll written on new pages. I am new to 'fpdf'.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `output` method will close the document. See [documentation](http://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/output/index.html).
After calling `output` you need to create another object.